# Can you declare multiple variables at once in Go?

Tags: go, variable-assignment

Is it possible to declare multiple variables at once using Golang?

For example in Python you can type this:

```
a = b = c = 80
```

and all values will be 80.

Comment: Sorry. In Go, the = operator creates a statement, not an expression. This is to avoid people doing fancy things with assignments inside other things that are hard to reason about.

Comment: what is the difference between a statement and an expression in programming?

Comment: @CharlieParker an expression has a value, and can go anywhere a value is expected (such as function parameters).. A statement is the basic unit of code.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
var a, b, c string
a = "foo"
fmt.Println(a)
```

You can do something sort of similar for inline assignment, but not quite as convenient:

```
a, b, c := 80, 80, 80
```

Comment: So you are not allowed to do something like `var a, b = "a", "b" string` according to go playground http://play.golang.org/p/jzRcG8Ox4A how sad :'( There is no way to do multiple declaration and at the same time assign them.

Comment: @CharlieParker It works. You just have to move the type declaration to the other side of the `=`: http://play.golang.org/p/cj0nZ-RbpI

Comment: This answer is false, the real answer to his question is: No you can't. I was searching for this to, but a, b = 80, 80 is not the same as a, b = 80

Comment: Doing `a = b = c = 80` in Python is not the same as doing `a, b, c := 80, 80, 80` in Go as in Python you are initializing 3 variables with one single value while in Go you need to provide 3 values. So in my opinion this does not answer the question.

Comment: in time of go1.16 one-liner looks like
`var x,y = a, b` or alike `x,y := a,b`

Answer (score 22):

Another way to do this is like this

```
var (
   a = 12
   b = 3
   enableFeatureA = false

   foo = "bar"
   myvar float64
   anothervar float64 = 2.4
)
```

Also works for const

```
const (
  xconst    = 5
  boolconst = false
)
```

Answer (score 18):

In terms of language specification, this is because the variables are defined with:

```
VarDecl     = "var" ( VarSpec | "(" { VarSpec ";" } ")" ) .
VarSpec     = IdentifierList ( Type [ "=" ExpressionList ] | "=" ExpressionList ) .
```

(From "[Variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)")

A list of identifiers for one type, assigned to one [expression](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Expression) or [ExpressionList](http://golang.org/ref/spec#ExpressionList).

```
const a, b, c = 3, 4, "foo"  // a = 3, b = 4, c = "foo", untyped integer and string constants
const u, v float32 = 0, 3    // u = 0.0, v = 3.0
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can and it is slightly more nuanced than it seems.

To start with, you can do something as plain as:

```
var a, b, x, y int  // declares four variables all of type int
```

You can use the same syntax in function parameter declarations:

```
func foo(a, b string) {  // takes two string parameters a and b
    ...
}
```

Then comes the short-hand syntax for declaring and assigning a variable at the same time.

```
x, y := "Hello", 10   // x is an instance of `string`, y is of type `int`
```

An oft-encountered pattern in Golang is:

```
result, err := some_api(...)  // declares and sets `result` and `err`
if err != nil {
    // ...
    return err
}

result1, err := some_other_api(...)   // declares and sets `result1`, reassigns `err`
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

So you can assign to already-defined variables on the left side of the `:=` operator, so long as at least one of the variables being assigned to is new. Otherwise it's not well-formed. This is nifty because it allows us to reuse the same error variable for multiple API calls, instead of having to define a new one for each API call. But guard against inadvertent use of the following:

```
result, err := some_api(...)  // declares and sets `result` and `err`
if err != nil {
    // ...
    return err
}

if result1, err := some_other_api(...); err != nil {   // result1, err are both created afresh, 
                                                       // visible only in the scope of this block.
                                                       // this err shadows err from outer block
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Several answers are incorrect: they ignore the fact that the OP is asking whether it is possible to set several variables to the same value in one go (sorry for the pun).

In go, it seems you cannot if a, b, c are variables, ie you will have to set each variable individually:

```
a, b, c := 80, 80, 80
```

But if a, b, c are constants, you can:

```
const (
        a = 80
        b
        c
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

long declaration

```
var varName1, varName2 string = "value","value"
```

short declaration

```
varName1,varName2 := "value1","value2"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this in the go-playground:
https://play.golang.org/

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a, b := "a", "b"; //Declare And Assign
    var c, d string;  //Declare Only
    fmt.Println(a,b);
    fmt.Println(c,d);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing is using var for package level assignment

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var (
    a, b, c = 80, 80 ,80
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(a, b, c)
}
```