# Go function declaration syntax

Tags: function, syntax, go

I have just started to learn [`Go`](http://golang.org) language and still trying to digest few things.

I wrote a function `add` as:

```
func add(a int, b int) int {
  return a + b
}
// works fine

func add(a, b) int {
  return a + b
}
// ./hello.go:7: undefined: a
// ./hello.go:7: undefined: b
// Digested: May be I need to give type

func add(a, b int) int {
  return a + b
}
// works fine interestingly 

func add(a int, b) int {
  return a + b
}
// ./hello.go:7: final function parameter must have type
```

I am really confused or due to lack of knowledge unable to understand the use case of

`final function parameter must have type`.

Comment: Go type declarations are on the form `<var>[, <var>]* <type>` so you are (in the last example) declaring a variable called int, with the type a and a variable b, without type.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071507/can-you-declare-multiple-variables-at-once-in-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned the [`IdentifierList`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#IdentifierList) in "[Can you declare multiple variables at once in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21072698/6309)": that explains `a, b int`.

But you need to have a type associated to each parameters of a function, which is not the case in the last `int a, b` parameter list.

The order is always `var type`, not `type var`, following the [variable declaration spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations):

```
 VarSpec     = IdentifierList ( Type  [ "=" ExpressionList ] | "=" ExpressionList ) .
```

You would always find a type *after* an `IdentifierList`: `a int` or `a, b int`

Comment: However, making order as 'var type' for argument 'a' results in the same error. But Thanks for 'IdentifierList'. It help me to got to understand its behavior.

Comment: I also want to add that In Go, whenever type of named function arguments are same then we can ignore type of all but last (http://tour.golang.org/#8)

Answer (score 1):

None of the above are quite correct. The answer is that Go allows you to explicitly give the type for each parameter, as *a int, b int*, or to use a shorter notation where you list two or more variables separated by commas, ending with the type. So in the case of *a,b int*  - both a and b are defined to be of type integer.  You could specify *a,b,c,d,e,f int* and in this case all of these variables would be assigned a type of *int*.  There is no "undefined" type here.  The problem with the (a,b) form of the declaration shown above produces an error because you have specified no type at all for the variables.