# Go error: Final function parameter must have type

Tags: go

I have an issue with my function. I'm getting a

```
final function parameter must have type
```

For this method

```
func (s *BallotaApi) PostUser(c endpoints.Context,userReq Users) (userRes Users, error) {

    c.Debugf("in the PostUser method")

    user := userManger.login(userReq)//return a Users Type 

    return user, nil
```

I read those threads but I can't figure out where I'm wrong. It looks like I declared everything.

[can-you-declare-multiple-variables-at-once-in-go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071507/can-you-declare-multiple-variables-at-once-in-go)

[go-function-declaration-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995539/go-function-declaration-syntax)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are naming your return parameters, you must name *all* of them

```
(userRes Users, err error)
```

That way, [return statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements) can apply.

As mentioned in [Function type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types):

> Within a list of parameters or results, the names (`IdentifierList`) must either **all be present or all be absent**.

If you try to name one and not the other, as [in this example](http://play.golang.org/p/HE3zYmd0-x), you will get:

```
func a() (b int, error) {
    return 0, nil
}
# command-line-arguments
/tmp/sandbox170113103/main.go:9: final function parameter must have type
```

---

[Dave C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55504/dave-c) reminds us that:

> [Named returns](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#named-result-parameters) should normally be limited to helping make better/clearer godoc documentation or when you need to change return values in a deferred closure.
>   Other than that they should be avoided.

Comment: [Named returns](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#named-result-parameters) should normally be limited to helping make better/clearer godoc documentation or when you need to change return values in a deferred closure. Other than that they should be avoided.

Comment: @DaveC I agree. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.