# How to declare to variables of different datatypes in a single statement in Go

Tags: go

I want to declare two variables of different datatypes(`string` and `error`) in a single statement in Go. I do not want to use the short declaration(`:=`) operator because I like specifying the type of the variable at declaration.

I am following a [Go tutorial from the Go docs](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/handle-errors). I have a function called `greetings.Hello()` that I am calling from another module. The `greetings.Hello()` function looks like this:

```golang
package greetings

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func Hello(name string) (string, error) {
    // If no name was given, return an error with a message
    if name == "" {
        return "", errors.New("empty name")
    }

    // If a name was received, return a value
    var message string = fmt.Sprintf("Welcome %v!", name)
    return message, nil
}
```

So as you can see, this function returns two values(a `string` and an `error`). So ultimately, I would have to assign the result of this function to two variables in the caller. I am calling the `greetings.Hello()` function from a module named `hello`. The main function of the `hello` module's main package looks like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "creating_modules/greetings"
)

func main() {
    log.SetPrefix("greetings: ")
    log.SetFlags(0)

    var message string, err error = greetings.Hello("")
    if err !=nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(message)
}
```

The `creating_modules/greetings` is the greetings module that contains the function `Hello()`. Most of the gophers tackle it like this:

```golang
message, error := greetings.Hello()
```

But I want to declare the variables along with their datatypes in a single statement. Also the two variables should be assigned the return values of `greetings.Hello()`. The above mentioned main function of the `hello` module returns an error when it is run because of the incorrect assignment, referring to this line:

```golang
var message string, err error = greetings.Hello("")
```

The Go compiler returns this error when this code is run using `go run`:

```
.\hello.go:14:20: syntax error: unexpected comma at end of statement
```

This issue can simply be reproduced by copy-pasting the code above(note that the `greetings` module is a local module so you will need to set the reference path for go tools using `go edit -replace`)

Another thing to be noted is that my question is different from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071507/can-you-declare-multiple-variables-at-once-in-go) because that question is about declaring variables with the **same data type** in a single statement whereas mine is about declaring multiple variables with **different data types** in a single statement.

P.S i won't be surprised to know that Golang does not have this feature

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> declare the variables along with their datatypes in a single statement

Not possible

Supporting clause from the language spec under [Variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)

> If a type is present, each variable is given that type. Otherwise, each variable is given the type of the corresponding initialization value in the assignment. If that value is an untyped constant, it is first implicitly converted to its default type;

So something like below could work by not specifying either of the types, but you could very well use short variable declarations using `:=` instead

```golang
var message, error = greetings.Hello()
```

---

But you can declare the variables explicitly with their type information and use the `=` assignment.

```golang
var message string
var err error

if message, err = greetings.Hello(""); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Or you can use implicit types:

`if message, err := greetings.Hello(""); ...`